# How to make relation between one model to another two models

Tags: python, django, models

I am creating simple forum site using Django framework, and I've created comment model, at this moment my comment model has OneToOne relation with Post, it means that every moment belong to specific post, but there is also another feature that I want to provide. Every comment model should has possibility to be related to Post object **OR** to Answer model. Answer model it is just as in Stack Overflow, you add a Post and another user can add an answer to it. I want to mention that answer is too related with Post with OneToOne relation I think it will be sufficient and dosen't need edition.
Summarizing: **How to allow adding comments to Post object or Answer object?**
Also I want to say that I was considering creating two comments models, namely PostComment, and AnswerComment but I've got a conclusion that is really bad solution.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def close(self):
        self.active = False
        self.save()


class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Comment to post: {0} added by {1} at {2}.".format(self.post.subject, self.author, self.published_date)


class Answer(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Answer to post: {0} added by {1} at {2}.".format(self.post.subject, self.author, self.published_date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Answer can be associated to only one post, so one to one
- comment can only be associated with one post, so one to one
- comment can only be associated with one answer, so one to one

Remember that the order of classes matters in Python. Place the comment class at the end, so that you can create one to one relationships between both Post and Answer. In the current position you can only do it with Post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
   ##
class Answer(models.Model):
   ##
class Comment(models.Model):
   post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   answer = models.OneToOneField(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Why answer field in comment is associated two times with Post but in two different fields?

Comment: @dannyxn sorry, that was a mistake.

Comment: No problem. I will try it later.

Comment: I disagree with @almost_a_beginner and the one to one implementation. Each Post (or Answer) can have several comments, so it's ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0):

If one Post object can have several comments, I think you need ForeignKey in your comment field. About Answer, maybe you can add another field to your comment pointing to the object Answer which is related, with a ForeignKey if several comments are permited for an answer.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem, it is about that my comment COULD be added to answer but also it COULD be added to post, I mean that I can comment both answer and post but how to tell to database that I want to comment i.e. post not answer?

Comment: Yes, if you add your comment to a post, fill the post field. If you add it to an answer, fill the answer field. Both in comment object. But maybe you are right and I don't understand your question, sorry if so.

Comment: So you say I should make two ForeignKey fields in my comment model?

Comment: I think so. One for Post, one for Answer. Both can be NULL. And manage in forms how to save it.

Comment: It could solve my problem I'll try it later and give you reward if it will work. Anyway it sounds little bit redundant. Thanks anyway.